# Inserting into MSMQ from SQL CLR in EXTERNAL_ACCESS instead of UNSAFE?

Tags: sql-server, clr, msmq, sqlclr

We're using MSMQ to insert records from a service into SQL Server tables in multiple locations.  I'd like to insert into this MSMQ queue from SQL Server - that way, rather than come up with my own way to add messages to each server, I can just piggyback on the existing infrastructure and code.

It looks like the best way to do this is by using a CLR.

However, all the code I've found to create MSMQ messages from a CLR require UNSAFE mode.  Is there a way to do it in EXTERNAL_ACCESS mode instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely because System.Messaging is not a supported library for CLR. Since it's not a supported library, it does not meet the requirements of SAFE or EXTERNAL_ACCESS.

Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx

Comment: Indeed.  And they didn't add it for 2012.  Rats.  But thanks!

Comment: Guess I'll be looking at powershell or SSIS to do this, then.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you need to call from T-SQL, you could always create a console app, create a job, add a step to call the app, then call the job with sp_start_job. That would allow you to reuse most of your CLR code.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought of doing it that way too.  I'm looking at both  [Powershell](http://jason.pettys.name/2011/11/07/write-msmq-messages-from-powershell/) and [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403349.aspx) (which requires that trick because it's a remote private queue that normally SSIS can't reach)